# ¿En qué casos es posible emplear "de que" correctamente?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

Mucha gente inserta **"de que"** en su forma de hablar, escribir y expresarse. ¿En qué casos es correcto decir "de que"?

Comment: De acuerdo a lo comentado [previamente](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55180/discussion-on-answer-by-diego-en-que-casos-es-posible-emplear-de-que-correcta), creo que deberías visitar las secciones de Tour y Help. Si dices "No considero la RAE como la autoridad máxima sobre temas lingüísticos" deberías clarificar qué tipo de respuesta y criterios van a satisfacer tu duda, especialmente si admites que las respuesta aportadas hasta la fecha "se están desviando un poco del tema; a causa de mi ambigua redacción de la pregunta". Pero si la RAE no es referencia máxima, esto será "opion-based"...

Comment: Te pido una disculpa por haber gastado tu tiempo al tratar de responder a una pregunta con ambigua redacción. Gracias por tu tiempo, Diego.

Comment: WOW. No hace falta ponerse así. Yo paso mucho tiempo en este sitio porque me gusta. Aparte, todos, cuando posteamos, no lo hacemos solo por quien pregunta sino también porque beneficia a todos los que en el futuro visitarán esta pregunta. Sigo recomendándote visitar Tour y Help y familiarizarte con el modelo de StackExchange. Estoy seguro de que puedes contribuir con grandes aportaciones.

Answer (score 3):

Recordemos:

- [dequeísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=vTr05If13D6tGOqCWV): Es el uso indebido de la preposición de delante de la conjunción que cuando la preposición no viene exigida por ninguna palabra del enunciado.
- [queísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5). Es la supresión indebida de una preposición (generalmente de) delante de la conjunción que, cuando la preposición viene exigida por alguna palabra del enunciado.

Cuando tengas dudas sobre si el `de` debe ir antes del `que`, sigue esta regla práctica: transforma la frase en pregunta. Por ejemplo

> Me alegro [de] que hayas venido.

Si lo trasformas en pregunta sería ""¿**De** qué me alegro?" y no "¿Qué me alegro?" y por tanto debe llevar la preposición.

> Te dije [de] que me trajeras el libro que te presté.

Preguntarías "¿De qué te dije?" o "¿Qué te dije?". Por tanto en este caso no llevaría la preposición. Por supuesto, como con casi todas las reglas, esta "regla práctica" puede tener su excepciones, pero te servirá en la mayoría de los casos.

Dicho esto, y como puedes ver en el enlace del [queísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5), **la preposición a veces exigida por alguna palabra de la oración o por el significado del verbo**. A veces depende del verbo que se usa

- antes (de) que, después (de) que, con tal (de) que.
- advertir, avisar, cuidar, dudar e informar en sus acepciones más comunes

> Te advertí de que eso podía pasar

Otras depende del significado de la oración, ya que se usa en ciertas locuciones

> hasta el punto de que /  a pesar de que

La información más completa, de nuevo, en el [enlace](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5), y como regla práctica, la explicada de transformarlo en pregunta (eso te dará un pista de si es correcto usar "**de** que" o si debe ser simplemente "que").

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55180/discussion-on-answer-by-diego-en-que-casos-es-posible-emplear-de-que-correcta).

Answer (score 2):

Adicionalmente a lo expresado por Diego, las proposiciones sustantivas ubicadas detrás de verbos que pueden ser gramaticalmente precedidas por "de" son aquéllas que pueden reemplazarse por pronombres como "algo" o "eso". Utilizando los ejemplos de Diego, decimos:

> Me alegro **de eso**.

PERO

> Te dije **algo**.

Existe otra construcción donde "de que" es gramatical, y es cuando se trata de una proposición sustantiva apositiva, es decir, que cumple la función de aposición respecto del sustantivo que la precede, a diferencia de las proposiciones adjetivas, que sólo llevan "de" cuando contienen un complemento introducido por esa preposición. Veamos con ejemplos:

> - La idea **de que** todos somos iguales ante la ley es uno de los pilares del sistema repuplicano. (La idea ES que todos somos iguales ante la ley, por lo que esta última estructura es una proposición sustantiva en aposición al sustantivo "idea", que inclusive puede reemplazarlo: Que todos somos iguales ante la ley es uno de los pilares del sistema republicano / Uno de los pilares del sistema republicano es que todos somos iguales ante la ley.) Es erróneo decir: *La idea que todos somos iguales ante la ley...
> - La idea **que** me transmitiste es errónea. (En este caso, "que me transmitiste" es una proposición adjetiva y no lleva "de".)
> - La idea **de que** se nutre ese plan es que cualquier medio es permitido con tal de llegar al fin. (En este caso, "de que se nutre ese plan" es una proposición adjetiva que lleva "de" porque esta preposición introduce el complemento del verbo "nutrirse": Ese plan se nutre **de** la idea, y por lo tanto "de" es correcto.)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero te respondo lo mismo que a Diego. Está bien dicho, mas no es la forma correcta de expresar la idea. Utilizaré tu mismo ejemplo. "La idea de que todos somos iguales ante la ley es uno de los pilares del sistema repuplicano" se puede reformular de la siguiente manera: "_La idea **de todos ser iguales** ante la ley es uno de los pilares del sistema republicano_". Comunica lo mismo que la versión anterior, pero de manera más "elegante" por así decirlo.

Comment: @user15165 Lamento estar totalmente en desacuerdo contigo (y de acuerdo con Diego). "La idea de todos ser iguales ante la ley" no es correcto castellano. Parece replicar la forma inglesa "the idea of everyone being equal before the law". En castellano, el infinitivo PRECEDE al sujeto: "la idea de ser todos iguales ante la ley". Mi respuesta y la de Diego son correctas de punta a punta.

Comment: Gracias por tu corrección sobre mi propuesta, aunque solamente estás agregando peso a mi punto. No veo por qué no tendría validez mi argumento ya que corregiste la propuesta que hice, viéndose así más elegante.

Comment: @user15165 Entiendo que "de que" puede interrumpir la fluidez de algunas frases, pero el **correcto *de que*** permite una flexibilidad y versatilidad de que el infinitivo carece. El infinitivo obviamente no expresa tiempo ni modo. Con "de que" podemos decir: "La idea de que somos/éramos/fúesemos/fuimos/habíamos sido/hubiéramos sido/seremos/seríamos iguales ante la ley" (entre otras variantes), mientras que "La idea de ser" es bastante limitado en cuanto a su aplicabilidad en oraciones que requieren una definición de tiempo y modo. En estos casos "de que" no sólo es POSIBLE sino NECESARIO.

Comment: GRACIAS. Esto responde mi duda. :)