# When should I use the spanish words "que", "de que", "en que", "por la que" as a translate for the english word "that"?

Tags: gramática

Below are sentences I made up with their translations I got from google translate.

The person **that** goes here. - *La persona **que** va aquí.*

The sign **that** she is gone. - *La señal **de que** ella se ha ido.*

The one **that** got away. - *El **que** se escapó.*

The moment **that** she comes back. - *El momento **en que** vuelve.*

The moment **that** we met. - *El momento **en que** nos conocimos.*

The moment **that** you come back. - *El momento **en que** vuelvas.*

The reason **that** she went away. - *La razón **por la que** se fue.*

The moment **that** got complicated. - *El momento **que** se complicó.*

The moment **that** became important. - *El momento *que* se hizo importante.*

If you could explain more on the difference between "que" and "de que", that'd be great. I just couldn't find more examples for "de que".

Comment: See https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/61/when-to-use-que-and-de-que and https://spanish.yabla.com/lesson-Que-or-De-que-That%27s-the-Question-648

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [¿En qué casos es posible emplear “de que” correctamente?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20043/5481)

Comment: Hi anj besinio, take a look at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20043/9385 and let us know if there's something you'd like clarified.  For now, I'm voting to close -- but please do give us an update (you can click on "edit" under your question).

Comment: The title of the question asks for more things than the last part of it. Mistaking when to use *de que* is a specific phenomenon that has been discussed elsewhere, but this looks like a more general question about prepositions + *que*.